# Create labeledPoints from a Spark DataFrame using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

I have a spark Dataframe with two coulmn "label" and "sparse Vector" obtained after applying Countvectorizer to the corpus of tweet.

When trying to train Random Forest Regressor model i found that it accept only Type  LabeledPoint.

Does any one know how to convert my spark DataFrame to LabeledPoint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which spark version you are using. Spark use spark ml instead of mllib.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Input data: Each row is a bag of words with a ID.
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (0, "a b c".split(" ")),
    (1, "a b b c a".split(" "))
], ["id", "words"])

# fit a CountVectorizerModel from the corpus.
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol="words", outputCol="features", vocabSize=3, minDF=2.0)

model = cv.fit(df)

result = model.transform(df).withColumn('label', F.lit(0))
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", numTrees=10)
rf.fit(result)
```

if You insist on mllib:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest

rdd = result \ 
          .rdd \
          .map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row['label'], row['features'].toArray()))
RandomForest.trainClassifier(rdd, 2, {}, 3)
```

Comment: Hi i am using spark 2.3.0 version

Comment: Hey its the same version with me. Can you use ml module instead of ml. Labelled point is working ith rdd's.

Comment: Can you help me setting its parameter in fact in mlli i used Train regressor but in this case of ml it is different class this is the used method pyspark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor(self, featuresCol="features", labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", maxDepth=5, maxBins=32, minInstancesPerNode=1, minInfoGain=0.0, maxMemoryInMB=256, cacheNodeIds=False, checkpointInterval=10, impurity="variance", subsamplingRate=1.0, seed=None, numTrees=20, featureSubsetStrategy="auto")

Comment: You should convert df to rdd and then import labelled point from mllib.regression. Answer is updated.

Comment: Does it supprot DataFrame or LabelledPoint type ??

Comment: Not support dataframe.

Comment: But in this example i think he trained it with DataFrame 
from numpy import allclose
>>> from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([
...     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0)),
...     (0.0, Vectors.sparse(1, [], []))], ["label", "features"])
>>> rf = RandomForestRegressor(numTrees=2, maxDepth=2, seed=42)
>>> model = rf.fit(df)

Comment: Can you try it with from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest. It uses it with rdd. Answer is updated.

Comment: yes i already try it with pyspark.mllib.trees but it does'nt work neither with DF or RDD i know it does'nt support DataFrame but with RDD i didn't understand from where theproblem comes

Comment: it worked with rdd in my case. What is error with it? Can you put sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Please explore my code example and sample data here https://github.com/jowwel/Sen_analyser-with-Pyspark-.git

Comment: Can You try: `from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest
rdd = transformed \ 
          .rdd \
          .map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row['label'], row['CV_vector'].toArray()))
RandomForest.trainClassifier(rdd, 2, {}, 3)`

Comment: Hamza i finally solve the problem but not with LabeledPoint i used pyspark.ml.RandomForestRegressor with Dataframe but it seems to give wrong predictions can you please guess the cause of thi wrong prediction i updated the previous link Kindly explore it https://github.com/jowwel/Sen_analyser-with-Pyspark-

Comment: Maybe because of indexes. ids, CategoricalIds and ml ids can be get mixed. Can you acccept my answer as correct one? I cant commenting questions.